# Are the constructible numbers algebraic?

Tags: math-history

The definition I found for algebraic numbers was as follows (a's are integers): A real number is *algebraic* if it is a solution to some polynomial equation...$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0  $$  We can also assert that any constructible number is the root of some polynomial degree $2^r$ $(r\ge0)$ with rational coefficients. Can there be a way to use this to prove that constructable numbers are algebraic?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Transformation_into_algebra

Comment: That “definition” of algebraic number doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think OP forgot to mention that the said number should  be a root of the polynomial equation.

Comment: @AnuragA Sure. Besides the fact that the $a_k$'s are not all equal to $0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The answer to the title question is yes

Comment: @AnuragA I clarified, thanks.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I clarified. Appreciate it.

Comment: This seems obvious. The root of a polynomial of any degree with rational coefficients is algebraic.